# Select an action with probability p

Tags: probability

What does it mean to say "do this with probability p"? Does it mean that if p > 0.5, we will do "this"?

How would you write the code or algorithm for doing something with the probability p?

Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's more or less: choose a random number between 0 and 1 then, if that's is less than or equal to `p`, do something.

For example, say `p` is equal to 0.75 (do something with a probability of 75%). When selecting random numbers in the range 0 through 1, about 75% of them will be 0.75 or less.

In terms of programming, you could code this up as (pseudo-code, obviously):

```
def do (action, probability):
    if rand() <= probability:
        action
```

Comment: Is there an inbuilt function in python that would do this and return a bool value ?

Comment: @SamuelGiftson: possibly. Given how "batteries included" Python is, it wouldn't surprise me :-) However, since what you seen to be asking for is a simple `bool_to_do_with_prob_p = random() <= p`, I'd question whether you'd need a separate function at all.